# mysql calculate duration from two dates

Tags: mysql, date, time

Hi I have a log database table in mysql which captures a start date and time and an end date and time.

The start and now the stop time is inserted to the record.

I have a third field which is duration which I would like displayed as hh:mm:ss

The schema looks like this at present

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `uid` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `stop` datetime NOT NULL,
  `duration` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `participants` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `recorded` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `rec_file` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Log File' AUTO_INCREMENT=106 ;
```

I'm trying to create a trigger which calculates the duration and writes it to the duration field as data is inserted

Currently the trigger I am trying to debug looks like this

```
BEGIN
     SET NEW.duration = (TIMEDIFF (NEW.start,NEW.stop)) ;
END
```

The result is the duration field remains set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000

Any suggestions on how to make this work are greatfully recived

Comment: I am not sure I understand the purpose of this table and from where insertions are coming. But why not taking the end time (and calculating the duration) before inserting it to the table in the code. If that is not possible I can think of writing stored procedure which will take the end date, calculate the result and do the insert.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. The issue is I don't get an accurate end date time from my app and thus only when the insertion occurs can I be sure I have a close enough end time. I certainly don't get a duration which is the usual way to calculate an end time. Currently I have a good start time from my app and I use the time stamp for an end time. I guess I have to do the calculation as part of the insert otherwise I will touch the record again and change the date. I have updated the question to include my insert command

Comment: You could convert the start and stop values to equivalent units, specifically UNIX timestamps, using the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function. I would then recommend storing the duration (measured in seconds) as an integer value, which will be easier to manipulate, I think. Alternatively, the FROM_UNIXTIME function could be of use.

Comment: If I started off simple. I have the start time this is the easy bit and I have the stop time also as this is when the insert command is happening. The last part of the puzzle is hoe I calculate and insert a duration in HH:MM:SS in to the database. What would the SQL command to do that during the insert process? I can change the database structure in order to make the command more elegant Thanks

Comment: I've updated the question. I have resolved hoe I get the start and stop datetime information and it is just how I calculate the duration as HH:MM:SS from the start field and stop field, the trigger I have written doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following :

1. Change `duration` type to `TIME` instead of `DATETIME`. According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff), the result returned by TIMEDIFF() is limited to the range allowed for `TIME` values.
   This is the reason you are receiving all zeros currently.
2. I assume that `stop` time will always be later than `start` time, so I would write the trigger in the following way:

   CREATE TRIGGER your_schema.insert_duration BEFORE INSERT ON your_schema.log
        FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.duration = TIMEDIFF(NEW.stop, NEW.start);

The result will be in HH:MM:SS format for `duration` field.

Comment: Yep that's done the job. With a little specific editing to get rid of a mysql error this does exactly what I was after. Thanks